# Convert number to exponent form with highest power possible

Tags: mathematical-optimization

As a school assignment we have to write a program which solves this issue. Since the program has to run efficient I am wondering what the best way is to approach this issue. Of course there you can just guess and try if it works, but that would not be efficient at all.

Could someone push me in the right direction how to solve:
n = b ^ e where e is the largest number possible?

For example, n = 16 would result in 2 ^ 4 instead of 4 ^ 2.

Comment: You mean integers, right?

Comment: `whatTheOPWantsMaybe[n_Integer] := 
     With[{exp = GCD @@ FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]]}, (n^(1/exp))^
       Defer[exp]]` ?

Comment: @Rojo Your CamelCase syntax is horrific

Comment: @Rojo, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I am having trouble understanding the syntax you are using, could you perhaps elaborate this a bit or do you have a link to this syntax? I could not find it in the help center.

Comment: @NLCJ In @Rojo 's comment, `exp=GCD @@ FactorInteger[n][[All,2]]` is `exp=Apply[GCD,FactorInteger[n][[All,2]]]`. This may be make it clearer.

Comment: @Rojo, I am trying to understand your formula, could you please take a look where I screw up?

http://pastebin.com/MzpMHnQ4

Comment: Why do you say you are screwing up? The code finds the exponent as the GCD of the number of times each prime factor appears. The rest is just a matter of displaying it in some form

Comment: Just wanted to reply and say that this was really helpful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`With[{s = Max[Cases[Log[Rest[Divisors[#]], #], _Integer]]}, {Surd[#, s], s}] &[yourNumberHere]`

Not surprisingly, most integers are there own "highest power". Here's from 2 to 1000:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You find the highest exponent for the base b: `b^IntegerExponent[n,b]`

Comment: The base is not determined upfront, so b and e are basically variables.